# The unitary implementation of $*$-isomorphism of $B(H)$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Is it possible to construct $*$-isomorphism of (factor von Neumann) algebra $B(H)$ which is not unitary implementable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a classic trick to produce the unitary. I was told once who this is due to, but I've unfortunately forgotten. Recall that, if $\xi,\eta \in H$, then $\eta \otimes \overline \xi$ denotes the rank-1 operator which sends $\zeta \mapsto \langle \xi,\zeta \rangle \eta$. Here, the inner-product is conjugate linear in the 1st slot. It's easy to check that $T \cdot ( \eta \otimes \overline \xi) = (T \eta) \otimes \overline \xi$ and $(\eta \otimes \overline \xi ) \cdot T^* = \eta \otimes \overline{T \xi}$ whenever $T \in B(H)$.

Let $\theta$ be a $*$-automorphism of $B(H)$.

> "Special" case: $\theta$ fixes a rank-1 projection.
>
> Let $\xi \otimes \overline \xi$ be a rank-1 projection fixed by $\theta$. Here, $\xi$ is a unit vector in $H$. We shall see that $\theta$ can be implemented by a unitary which fixes $\xi$. Imagine for a moment that we already have such an implementing unitary $U$. Then, for any $\eta \in H$, we have
> $$ (U    \eta ) \otimes \overline \xi  = (U \eta ) \otimes \overline{U \xi} = U ( \eta \otimes \overline{\xi}) U^* = \theta(\eta \otimes \overline{\xi})$$
> whence
> $$U(\eta) = \theta(\eta \otimes \overline \xi) \xi.$$
> Since formula above only depends on $\theta$, we can use it do *define* $U$ and then check $U$ is indeed a unitary with the desired properties.

I left out the details, but they aren't too bad.

> General case:
>
> Fix some rank-1 projection $e$. If $\theta$ does not already fix $e$, then choose a unitary $W$ such that $W \theta(e) W^* = e$. Then, $W \theta( \cdot ) W^*$ does fix $e$ and this new automorphism is unitarily implemented if and only if $\theta$ is.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'd like to know how invented this trick.

Comment: @MartinArgerami: I think you are implying sot/wot density is needed when we check $U$ implements $\theta$, but I don't think this is the case... Indeed, supposing we have already checked the formula $U\eta=\theta(\xi\otimes\overline\eta)\xi$ defines a unitary, then we just observe that, for any $T \in B(H)$ and $\eta \in H$, we have $U T \eta = \theta ((T \eta) \otimes \overline \xi) \xi = \theta( T  (\eta \otimes \overline \xi)) \xi =\theta(T) \theta(\eta \otimes \overline \xi)\xi= \theta(T) U \eta$. Since $\eta$ is arbitrary, this means that $UT = \theta(T) U$, i.e. $UTU^* =\theta(T)$.

Comment: You are totally right. Very nice trick.

Comment: @MartinArgerami: Yes, it's a nice one. I think it goes way back to Kaplansky?

Comment: Most likely. It should have been obvious to Murray and von Neumann, I think, but who knows. Just today I was thinking about this stuff, but in the case where $\theta:B (H)\to B (K) $.

Comment: @MartinArgerami: Curiosity sent me poking around in the literature. The earliest thing like it I found is Theorem 11 in [this paper](http://www.math.uci.edu/~brusso/kadison66.pdf) of Kadison, which is about derivations. Which makes sense because the argument also works to show that a 1-parameter group of $*$-automorphisms $(\theta_t)$ possessing a fixed rank-1 projection is implemented by 1-parameter unitary group $(U_t)$. But that is 1966, and it was probably known earlier!

Comment: I wonder how you found that :) I would expect this to be from the 50s at the latest, but maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\theta:B(H)\to B(H)$ be a $*$-automorphism. Fix an orthonormal basis $\{\xi_j\}$ of $H$, and write $E_{jj}$ for the corresponding rank-one projections, i.e. $E_{jj}\xi=\langle\xi,\xi_j\rangle\,\xi_j$. We can expand $\{E_{jj}\}_j$ to a system of matrix units $\{E_{kj}\}_{k,j}$, where $E_{kj}\xi=\langle\xi,\xi_j\rangle\,\xi_k$.

Next notice that $\theta(E_{11})$ is also a rank-one projection (because $\theta$ being an automorphism forces it to be minimal). Let $\eta_1$ be a unit vector in the range of $\theta(E_{11})$.

Define $U:H\to H$, linear,  by $U\xi_j=\theta (E_{j1})\eta_1$. Then $$\langle U\xi_j,U\xi_k\rangle=\langle \theta (E_{1k}E_{j1})\eta_1,\eta_1\rangle=\delta_{kj}=\langle\xi_j,\xi_k\rangle. $$So $U $ is  a unitary and $\{\eta_j\}$, where $\eta_j=U\xi_j $, is an orthonormal basis (the observation that $\theta(E_{11})$ is minimal is necessary to guarantee that $U$ is onto).

Note that $\theta(E_{kj})$ is a rank-one operator sending $\eta_j\to\eta_k$ (because $\theta(E_{kj})\theta(E_{j1})=\theta(E_{kj}E_{j1})=\theta(E_{k1})$); this means that $\theta(E_{kj})\xi=\langle\xi,\eta_j\rangle\,\eta_k$. Then
$$
UE_{kj}U^*\eta_t=UE_{kj}\xi_t=\delta_{j,t}U\xi_k=\delta_{j,t}\eta_k=\langle\eta_t,\eta_j\rangle\,\eta_k=\theta(E_{kj})\eta_t.
$$

As finite linear combinations of the $E_{kj}$ are weakly dense and $\theta$ is normal (which implies weak-continuous on bounded sets), we get $\theta=U\cdot U^*$.

Comment: There's something wrong here, you can't just choose the $\eta_j \in \mathrm{range}(\theta(E_{jj}))$ willy-nilly. For example, taking $\theta = \mathrm{id} : M_2(\mathrm{C}) \to M_2(\mathrm{C})$ and $\eta_1 = (1,0), \eta_2=(0,1)$, your argument gives me the freedom to choose $\eta_1 = (z,0)$ and $\eta_2 = (0,w)$ for any $z,w$ with $|z|=|w|=1$. But conjugation by the correponding unitary $\left( \begin{smallmatrix} z & 0 \\ 0 & w \end{smallmatrix} \right)$ is not the identity automorphism, unless $z=w$.

Comment: Good catch. I have edited accordingly.